# chatterbot: def handler(msg) - Chatbot doesn't recognize my Telegram ID

Tags: python, telegram, chatterbot

I decided for my test chatbot on Telegram to create a function to limit the ability to speak only to a few users. I thought to create a .csv to put the Telegram user ID (the file is in the program folder). However, when I go to start the chat or write with my bot, I get the non-acknowledgment message ("I don't talk with strangers, dear ") with my ID Telegram. But I already put it in the file! So, I tried to see the data of chat with the Telegram API "getUpdate", but it doesn't appear (   {"ok":true,"result":[]}  ).
This is my function:

`def handle(msg):

```
global bot
global chatter
global language

chat_id = msg['chat']['id']
sender = msg['from']['id']

users = listusers()


if checkuserid == 1:
    verified = 0
    if users != "":
        for usr in users:
            if str(sender) == usr:
                verified = 1
    if verified == 0:
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "I don't talk with strangers, dear "+str(sender))
        #write this user in the list of attempted accesses
        if attemptsfile != '':
            lines = ''
            if os.path.isfile(attemptsfile):
                text_file = open(attemptsfile, "r")
                lines = text_file.read()
                text_file.close()
            lines = lines + str(datetime.datetime.now()) + " --- UserdID: " + str(sender) + " DENIED \n"
            text_file = open(attemptsfile, "w")
            text_file.write(lines)
            text_file.close()
        return

command = ''


try:
    if msg['text'] != '':
        command = msg['text']
        print('Got command: ' + command)
except:
    print("No text in this message")


if command == '/time':
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id, str(datetime.datetime.now()))
elif '/adduser' in command:
    if len(command.split(' ')) > 1:
        usrname = command.split(' ')[1]
        adduser(usrname)
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "User "+usrname+" added")
elif '/deluser' in command:
    if len(command.split(' ')) > 1:
        usrname = command.split(' ')[1]
        deluser(usrname)
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "User "+usrname+" deleted")
elif command == '/help':
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "/adduser /deluser /time /exit")
elif command == '/exit':
    global active
    active = False
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "The bot will shutdown in 10 seconds")
elif command != '':
    answer = chatter.reply(command)
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id, str(answer))
```

`

Comment: double-check `listusers()`

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: most probably the problem is within `listusers()`. check it again yourself or post the full function here.

Comment: Solved!!! Thanks a lot! :)